# How to setup JPA console or something similar to execute JPQL queries?

Tags: eclipse, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I did lot of web searching before posting the question, but I did not find any working solution yet.

I am developing **Spring Boot + Spring Data JPA and Spring Batch** project. In this project, I am using `JpaPagingItemReader` item reader and some custom reader. I am using Repository, Native queries too in order to fetch the data.

I am using JPA Console, but that expects the persistent.context xml file etc., but I dont have that file as I am using Spring Boot.

Is there is any way to execute JPA or JPQL queries which in eclipse/STS which are  possible with InteliJ Idea ?

Comment: in the eclipse market is the hiberObjects available on Eclipse STS? I would suggest moving to intelliJ since there are a lot features.

Comment: @Sidhartha Philander - Is not open source and community edition doesn't have good integration with Spring Boot